# Using "..., the" instead of "The ..."

Tags: articles

I wonder to know why the article "the" is taken from the beginning of the subject and put to the end of it? For example, "Butterfly effect, the" instead of "The butterfly effect".

Comment: For ease of indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting "..., the" after the word or phrase makes it **easier to find in an alphabetical index**.

For instance, let's say you want to list the following items in alphabetical order: the butterfly effect, random variables, the Taj Mahal, waterfalls, steak and kidney pudding, the Dalai Lama, Stack Exchange. Which of the following lists is better?

1. Listing them in alphabetical order with "The ..." at the start where relevant:

   - Random variables
   - Stack Exchange
   - Steak and kidney pudding
   - The butterfly effect
   - The Dalai Lama
   - The Taj Mahal
   - Waterfalls
2. Listing them in alphabetical order with "..., the" at the end:

   - Butterfly effect, the
   - Dalai Lama, the
   - Random variables
   - Stack Exchange
   - Steak and kidney pudding
   - Taj Mahal, the
   - Waterfalls

With the first method, you often have to guess whether or not there's a "the" at the start (it's not always clear, is it? should you look under "butterfly effect" or "the butterfly effect"?) There's also going to be a massive section under "the", and probably "a" too, even though these aren't really important words in the items.

The second method makes the items much easier to find, especially in a very long list, such as in an encyclopedia or textbook. This is why items in alphabetical lists are often listed with "..., the" at the end rather than "The ..." at the start.

Comment: Sure it is helpful for indexing. But it is very annoying when it appears in the middle of the text.